# Error in SQL Syntax on Google App Engine Cloud SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, google-app-engine

When trying to create a user named `admin` on a MySQL 5.5 database on Google's cloud sql on App Engine, I get the following error.

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ''Get' at line 1
```

This is the SQL that I ran:

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
```

Looking at the SQL statement I used is there missing something in my sql statement or is there a change in the 5.5 version of MySQL?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you have double single quotes before password: `''password'`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Its a copy and paste screw up, but just to make sure I just did it again and it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with the SQL statement you used to grant the permissions to the user as I've been able to create one by using your SQL clause (without the double quote) and to grant those permissions.

First, I used

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

On the other hand, as noted in the Cloud SQL FAQ,

> Google Cloud SQL does not support SUPER privileges, which means that
>   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES statements will not work. As an alternative, you
>   can use GRANT ALL ON `%`.*.

So your original statement will fail.

You should use something like

```
GRANT ALL ON `%`.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Please, be aware of the special ` quotes around the percentage sign (%).